# Is there a way to decrypt a string with 2 different salt keys to get 2 different outcomes

Tags: php, encryption

I want to make a system where you for example have the encrypted string "qbGOwSX8UQ2mvGBAbDrgz4TqitvmMqqVcTmFyaSxjlk="
and using the salt key "england" it will output "hello world" 
and using the salt key "france" it will output "I love cake"
or something like that. I want to make it in php.

Anyone got any ideas on how to approach such a problem?

Comment: You may need to clarify some of the terms you're using to get an answer. At a general level salt is used to add "randomness" to a hash function (e.g. SHA-2), while a key is used with encryption algorithms (e.g. AES). Hash functions are designed to be one way, so presumably you are talking about encryption, as you're looking for something reversible. It would also be useful to understand how secure this needs to be (i.e. is it for messages between friends or for securing state secrets).

Comment: I was thinking about longer texts, about half the length of a normal article, but I could split that text up into equally sized parts.

Answer (score 3):

Research the [One Time Pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad).  Given the right key, any encrypted text can be decrypted to any message of the same length.

For example, if I start with "ABC" as my cyphertext, then alphabetic shifts of 0, 1, 2 give "ACE", while shifts of 1, 3, 1 give "BED".

Comment: thanks, that helped me give another view to my problem :)) It'll be easier to find a way to do it